# Any Javascript framework with just one API that supports both Desktop and Mobile?

Tags: javascript, mobile, extjs, frameworks, dojo

Any Javascript framework with just one API that supports both Desktop and Mobile (includes phones and tablets)? If not, why isn't there? What happens if I need to port the website from Desktop experience to Mobile experience, do I have to rewrite the entire website?

What do you think about Dojo or Ext JS?

Answer (score 1):

Use Titanium at http://www.appcelerator.com/ for mobile development

Comment: We are looking at this as a potential candidate as well. I'd be interested in hearing what people think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha has ExtJS and Touch. Both are very similar in API and worth taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for HTML5 standard based mobile/desktop application, then look at Sench Touch. It works on mobile as well as desktop. Checkout the examples - http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/ - on your desktop (HTML5 compliant browsers) or on your mobile/iPad and see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo 1.7 works no issue both on desktop and mobile, the only complain for me is the drag and drop API doesn't support touch for now